# DownloadStringAsync inside a Backgroundworker vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, asynchronous, backgroundworker, webclient

I am very confused on how to do this.

I have a bunch of background workers spawning that all need to use the Webclients downloadstringasync method.

My problem is how to heck do i return the data from the downloaded string (once the download string completed event happens), back to the background worker that started the downloadstring?

I hope that makes sense.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: The reason I am doing that way is so i can make it timeout by using cancelasync as i am using proxies that like to cause the normal downloadstring to hang.

Answer (score 0):

There's no point at all in using the async version in a worker thread. The code is already running asynchronously, thanks to the BackgroundWorker.

So just use DownloadString() instead, problem solved.

Comment: -1 asych and concurrent are slightly different thing. Using a background worker consumes a thread. Async callbacks do not consume a thread. On a x64 machine a thread uses 8mb of memory. As well as other resources.

Comment: @HansPassant That is true. But you said there was NO point to using the async version, in a worker thread. Using a thread pool thread does not detract from the cost of a thread. A thread is still used. If you have 1000 requests, using Synchronous `DownloadString()` with a Background thread will either block when the threadpool maxes out, or new threads will be created on the threadpool. As for using a background worker with `DownloadStringAsync()`, it moves the request creation onto a worker thread, which in UI intensive apps, can be important.

Comment: He's already using a BGW.  He can do two things with it, calling DownloadString() or blocking it until DownloadStringAsync completes.  Only one of these choices makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `WebClient.DownloadStringAsync` it runs on a different thread.  You will need to add event handlers to get notified when events happens.

For example:

- [WebClient.DownloadStringCompleted Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadstringcompleted.aspx)

Also, here is some sample code that downloads an image from Google Async.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;

namespace WebDownload
{
    class Program
    {
        static AutoResetEvent autoEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(DownloadCompleted);

            string fileName = Path.GetTempFileName();
            client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png"), fileName, fileName);

            // Wait for work method to signal. 
            if (autoEvent.WaitOne(20000))
                Console.WriteLine("Image download completed.");
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Timed out waiting for image to download.");
                client.CancelAsync();
            }
        }

        private static void DownloadCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Error != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Error.Message);
                if (e.Error.InnerException != null)
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Error.InnerException.Message);
            }
            else
            {
                // We have a file - do something with it
                WebClient client = (WebClient)sender;

                // display the response header so we can learn
                Console.WriteLine("Response Header...");
                foreach(string k in client.ResponseHeaders.AllKeys)
                    Console.WriteLine("   {0}: {1}", k, client.ResponseHeaders[k]);
                Console.WriteLine(string.Empty);

                // since we know it's a png, let rename it
                FileInfo temp = new FileInfo((string)e.UserState);
                string pngFileName = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "DesktopPhoto.png");
                if (File.Exists(pngFileName))
                    File.Delete(pngFileName);

                File.Move((string)e.UserState, pngFileName);  // move to where ever you want
                Process.Start(pngFileName);     // display the photo for the fun of it
            }

            // Signal that work is finished.
            autoEvent.Set();
        }


    }
}
```